# How to find $\int \frac{x\sqrt{1+\tan ^2x}}{\cos x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to perform integration by substitution of the following expression?

$$\int \frac{x\sqrt{1+\tan ^2x}}{\cos x}dx$$

I've already reached to this part of the solution, but I'm having a hard time, figuring out, what to do next.

Step 1:  $$=\int\frac{x\sqrt{\frac{\cos ^2x+\sin ^2x}{\cos ^2x}}}{\cos x}dx$$
Step 2: $$=\int \frac{x\sqrt{1/\cos ^2x}}{\cos x}dx$$
Step 3: $$=\int \frac{x\sec x}{\cos x}dx$$
Step 4: $$\int \frac{x}{\cos ^2x}dx$$
but what next?

Comment: Well, start with $\tan^{2}(x) + 1 = \sec^{2}(x)$.

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, **possible strategies, your current progress,** why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: Yep I've already reached to this part of the solution,but I'm having a hard time, figuring what to do next.
x.sqrt(cos^2x+sin^2x/cos^2x)dx/cosx= x.sqrt(1/cos^2x)dx/cosx = (x.secx)dx/cosx.
but what next?

Comment: Next time try integral calculator online for indefinite Integration.

Answer (score 3):

Its probably easiest to write the integral as:
$$I=\int x\sec^2 x\,dx$$
now do integration by parts: $u=x\Rightarrow u'=1,v'=\sec^2x\Rightarrow v=\tan x$ so:
$$I=x\tan x-\int\tan x\,dx$$
can you finish it from here?

Comment: Yes definitely thanks for guiding!